# Windows Bat check if php script runnin

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I am using a bat to run a php on win2003 scheduler. Is there a way to check the processes and see if the file is still running.

Comment: Here you may find some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Answer (score 1):

How about your batch file like this: (pseudocode, as it's been a while)

```
:makerandom
make som random var, microtime, whatever, we call it %x%
check if file exist, if it does, goto makerandom
call the script with %x% as argument
:check
if file exist %x% goto check
:done
```

in the php-script:

```
create the file specified by the argument
... script here ...
delete the file
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scheduled task's .php file: Use `getmypid()` to get the PHP process' ID (PID) and save it to a file.

Next time your .php file is called, use `$tasks = shell_exec('tasklist.exe');` to get a list of all active processes, then read the previously saved PID and look it up.

Honestly, I don't know if this is the best solution or not.

Comment: this only on for 24 to 48 hours; initial load of data

Comment: calling tasklist.exe didnt output anything

Answer (score 0):

Try out Sysinternals Process Utilities.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682

The pslist utility is just what you need (given a pid tells if it's running setting an env variable)

Regards

PS: with pslist I suggest evaluating also the pskill utility