# How do I periodically check if a program is running in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

I've heard of batch scripts, but couldn't find any official documentation on it. Is this possible with batch scripts?

Also, can it send emails?

EDIT: Basically I need to check if a certain application is running, and send an email if it isn't as a notification. Can this be done via batch scripts?

Comment: It seems like someone else on here has already asked the same question!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PsList from Sysinternals to find out what is there:

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682
```

and then kill it with PsKill:

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683
```