# How to check if a process is running via a batch script in Windows Server 2003

Tags: process, batch-file, windows-server-2003

I want use a batch file to check if a process is running on Windows Server 2003 and then start a new instance if not.

This is the same question as

[How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

but for Windows Server 2003. The answer is slightly different, however I don't have enough rep to answer that one so I'll post it here for future searches.

..dam. I need to wait 8 hours. Answer coming soon.

Comment: Seems like you should now be able to post your answer in that thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided in the link works for XP, however in Windows Server 2003 the line

```
 tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FO CSV > search.log
```

returns "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria." which is then read as the process is running.

I don't have a heap of batch scripting experience so my soulution is to then search for the process name in search.log and pump the results into another file and search that for any output.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FO CSV > search.log

FINDSTR notepad.exe search.log > found.log

FOR /F %%A IN (found.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

start notepad.exe

:end

del search.log
del found.log
```

Hope this helps someone else, if I get enough rep I'll add it to the original question's answers.

Ben