# Check if File is Open

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to move files from a UNIX/Windows directory over to a SharePoint directory via a batch file.  I know that the command that I want to use is just a simple `move g:\...\*.* z:\` but I do not want to try to move any file that is currently open.  Is there a way to check if files in a directory are open/in use and then only perform the move on the non open files?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

Comment: which OS controls source directory? Is it local fs (ntfs)?

Comment: The batch file will be run on a Windows Server machine that has both of the directories mapped.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix you could use [fuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_%28Unix%29), on Windows Sysinternals [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) utilities respectively to query what processes have a file open.

Bear in mind that both of those must be executed on a system which controls source filesystem, not on your copy machine.

General problem with this approach is that check-move operation is not atomic: you may never be sure that file status have not changed **after** you checked but **before** you start moving/copying, however if I correctly assume that you have a scenario with producer which puts something on your shared drive - to be consumed by Sharepoint, and you want to make sure it's 'baked' before you attempt move - then a common practice is to control this on producer side by moving it to shared resource only when work on it is completed. If you have no direct control over the producer you can achieve this by using utitilies mentioned above