# what is the windows equivalent of the command "date+%s"

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, batch-file, unix-timestamp

I'm writing a batch script and I need the unix time. It's easy under linux, but I can't figure out how to do this in windows.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us) will help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a native batch solution that should work in any locale. It uses WMIC to get the current local time in a locale independent manner. Everything else is a "simple" matter of string parsing and basic math.

```
:UnixTime  [ReturnVar]  [TimeStamp]
::
:: Computes the Unix time from the current local time as reported by the
:: operating system. The Unix time is the number of seconds that have elapsed
:: since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), January 1, 1970, not
:: counting leap seconds.
::
:: The result is returned in variable ReturnVar,
:: or the result is echoed if ReturnVar is not specified
::
:: If the TimeStamp is provided in the 2nd parameter, then the Unix time for
:: the TimeStamp is computed, rather then for the current time.
::
:: The TimeStamp must have the same format as used by WMIC:
::
::   YYYYMMDDhhmmss.ffffffSzzz
::
:: where:
::
::   YYYY   = gregorian year
::   MM     = month
::   DD     = day
::   hh     = hour in 24 hour format
::   mm     = minute
::   ss     = seconds
::   ffffff = fractional seconds (microseconds)
::   S      = timezone sign: + or -
::   zzz    = timezone: minutes difference from GMT
::
:: Each component must be zero prefixed as needed to maintain the proper width.
::
:: The ReturnVar parameter must be provided in order to use the TimeStamp.
:: A ReturnVar of "" will function the same as no ReturnVar. This enables the
:: specification of a TimeStamp without an actual ReturnVar.
::
@echo off
setlocal
set "ts=%~2"
if not defined ts for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined ts set "ts=%%A"
set /a "yy=10000%ts:~0,4% %% 10000, mm=100%ts:~4,2% %% 100, dd=100%ts:~6,2% %% 100"
set /a "dd=dd-2472663+1461*(yy+4800+(mm-14)/12)/4+367*(mm-2-(mm-14)/12*12)/12-3*((yy+4900+(mm-14)/12)/100)/4"
set /a ss=(((1%ts:~8,2%*60)+1%ts:~10,2%)*60)+1%ts:~12,2%-366100-%ts:~21,1%((1%ts:~22,3%*60)-60000)
set /a ss+=dd*86400
endlocal & if "%~1" neq "" (set %~1=%ss%) else echo %ss%
exit /b
```

*Note that this solution has a limited life span. It will cease to work on 2038-01-19 when the Unix time exceeds the maximum value of a signed 32 bit integer.*

***EDIT*** - The code has been edited to support conversion of a timestamp string on the command line instead of the current local time. The precise range of times supported is 1901-12-13 20:45:52.000000 through 2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999 GMT. Times prior to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000 will yield negative values.

Comment: @pizza - That is news to me. The script works fine for me on Windows 7 without admin privs. I'm pretty sure it works on other Windows versions as well. Did you actually test the script? And if so, what Windows version?

Comment: winxp: Failed to register mof file(s).
Only the administrator group members can use WMIC.EXE.
Reason:Win32 Error: Access is denied.

Comment: @pizza - I confirmed the code works on Vista and Windows 7 without admin rights (at least by default). WMIC is available on XP Professional, but not XP Home. I'm not sure what the default privilege requirements are on XP Professional.

Comment: There is a somewhat related posts here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4783062/1276280 note the comments. Try create a new user id on 7/vista without special authority, I suspect it does not work either.

Comment: I just tried on 7pro, it does work on a normal user id. Just not XP unfortunately. Otherwise the batch is pretty cool.

Answer (score 4):

You can use vbscript in windows, the interpreter is available on your system.

```
'--------------------epoch.vbs----------------------- 
option explicit
dim s,o,z
for each o in GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem")
z=o.CurrentTimeZone
next
s=DateDiff("s", "01/01/1970 00:00:00", Now())-(60*z)
wscript.echo(s)
wscript.quit
```

Comment: This does not take into account time zone differences. It will also be affected by daylight savings time.

Comment: changed to deal with timezones.

Answer (score 3):

If by "unix time" you mean the [epoch second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then Windows doesn't include tools to produce that.  Instead, you can install third-party tools.  For example:

- Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).
- Find the `date` binary (under `C:\Cygwin\` or wherever you installed it)
- Use it as you would in Linux.

Alternately, per the awesome comment on this answer, you could install [GNU Coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) which also include a `date` command.  It includes a number of other tools that you may not need, but then, so does Cygwin.

Comment: No need to install Cygwin just to get a single tool. Most (all?) GNU tools can be downloaded and used without Cygwin

Comment: +1... it's the right answer. There are a number of other Unixy layers for Windoze, UWIN etc, but everybody uses Cygwin. Also might be worth explaining that Windows ain't Unix, of course you can't get epoch seconds (natively)!

Comment: I tried GnuWin32 on Windows and it doesn't work for dates before 1970. On Linux it works and it returns negative numbers. date +%s --date "31 Dec 1969" should return -86400 but it returns "invalid date" to me