# Is there an easy way to get current time, to nearest millisecond, from windows command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line, time, command

I note that you can use `echo %time:~0,12%` to get the time to the nearest 100th of a second.

However, ideally I would like to get the time since 00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970 in seconds to three decimal places (eg `1352822663.863`).

It seems like there are no easy ways to do this... could anyone recommend a good starting point?

Comment: There's no point, clock accuracy is ~16 msec.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the windows equivalent of the command "date+%s"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124572/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-command-dates) That question has a few answers that provide what you are looking for, also known as Unix time, or POSIX time.