# Lotus Script - check if windows process is running

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm new to programming. I've made a simple codeblock that runs a Windows program POSTOPEN when I open an application in Lotus Notes 8.5.3 (basic)

```
' [ML]Check if user is member of the [ConnectClient] role. 
ipConnect = HasRole("[ConnectClient]") 
If ipConnect = True Then 
    Dim result As Integer
    Print "Postopen: Has [ConnectClient] role - starting Connect Client"
    result = Shell("c:\program files (x86)\ipvision\Connect\connect.exe", 1) 
End If
```

Is there any way for Lotus Script to check if a Windows process is already running?

Thanks

Comment: If it is only your code which started the process, use shellid instead of shell - you will get process ID which can be then checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this snippet: http://blog.panagenda.com/pub/panablog.nsf/d6plinks/FLOR-7D5KZR
I assume following code could work: http://coderstalk.blogspot.sk/2009/10/list-windows-xp-running-process-and.html

```
Option Explicit

Dim oProc, oWMIServ, colProc
Dim strPC, strList
Dim StrSpace

strPC = "."

Set oWMIServ = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strPC & "\root\cimv2")    

Set colProc = oWMIServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

strSpace = string(20," ")
strList = "ProcName" & strSpace & vbTab & "ProcID" & vbCrLf & string(45,"-")

For Each oProc In colProc
    strSpace = string(28 - len(oProc.Name)," ")
    strList = strList & vbCrLf & oProc.Name & strSpace & vbTab & oProc.ProcessId
Next
```

So once you have process ID (assuming you have ran your task by shellid function), execute chceck for all running processes and determine whether there is processid you have started.

BTW: the same approach can be used to terminate such process. Just google for >"winmgmts" lotusscript<.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Shell` to run `tasklist` and direct the output to a file. Then read the file in LotusScript and check if the process is listed there.

**edit**

Looks like you can even check if a specific process if running using `tasklist`:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq connect.exe" /FO CSV > search.log
```

[How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)