# Batch program to to check if process exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, cmd

I want a batch program, which will check if the process `notepad.exe` exists.

**if** `notepad.exe` exists, it will end the process,

**else** the batch program will close itself.

Here is what I've done:

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"
exit
```

But it doesn't work. What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: Why don't you call `taskkill` without verifying whether the task exists?

Comment: `taskkill` doesn't change the errorlevel for me...

Comment: @Andriy M I want to check if the process exist. then end the process or close itself.

Comment: Your script seems to close itself regardless of whether the image is found & killed or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`TASKLIST` does not set errorlevel.

```
echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"
exit
```

should do the job, since ":" should appear in `TASKLIST` output only if the task is NOT found, hence `FIND` will set the errorlevel to `0` for `not found` and `1` for `found`

Nevertheless,

taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"

will kill a notepad task if it exists - it can do nothing if no notepad task exists, so you don't really need to test - unless there's something else you want to do...like perhaps

```
echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"&exit
```

which would appear to do as you ask - kill the notepad process if it exists, then exit - otherwise continue with the batch

Comment: Rather than checking `if errorlevel`, this can be even further simplified with [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php).

Comment: Perhaps it's better to `find "notepad.exe"` since the output is translated and we cannot be sure whether `:` appears in all languages.

Answer (score 27):

This is a **one line solution**.

It will run taskkill only if the process is really running otherwise it will just info that it is not running.

```
tasklist | find /i "notepad.exe" && taskkill /im notepad.exe /F || echo process "notepad.exe" not running.
```

This is the output in case the process was running:

```
notepad.exe           1960 Console                   0    112,260 K
SUCCESS: The process "notepad.exe" with PID 1960 has been terminated.
```

This is the output in case not running:

```
process "notepad.exe" not running.
```

Comment: for me it works in Windows 10, I use it in several scripts.

Comment: maybe i missed something

Comment: It's also nice that the errorlevel still ends up being 0 if the process isn't running.

Comment: Not really because then the batch file continues. What if you want to keep it looping "watching" for the process to end (or be there). It's complicated this!

Answer (score 13):

`TASKLIST` doesn't set an exit code that you could check in a batch file. One workaround to checking the exit code could be parsing its standard output (which you are presently redirecting to `NUL`). Apparently, if the process is found, `TASKLIST` will display its details, which include the image name too. Therefore, you could just use `FIND` or `FINDSTR` to check if the `TASKLIST`'s output contains the name you have specified in the request. Both `FIND` and `FINDSTR` set a non-null exit code if the search was unsuccessful. So, this would work:

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" | find /i "notepad.exe" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe") else (
  specific commands to perform if the process was not found
)
exit
```

There's also an alternative that doesn't involve `TASKLIST` at all. Unlike `TASKLIST`, `TASKKILL` does set an exit code. In particular, if it couldn't terminate a process because it simply didn't exist, it would set the exit code of 128. You could check for that code to perform your specific actions that you might need to perform in case the specified process didn't exist:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 128 (
  specific commands to perform if the process
  was not terminated because it was not found
)
exit
```

Comment: I found if the image name, includes the file extension, over 25 characters, the "Image Name" column in the tasklist output will be truncated, which makes the "find" command with image name doesn't work. However, detect only by the ":" character seems too loose, I am afraid it may happens in the positive output of the future versions. Is there any other better way to do so?

Comment: @Elliott: If you store the executable's name in a variable, you can then use the whole value in `tasklist` and only the first 25 chars in `find`: `tasklist /fi "imagename eq %imgname%" | find /i "%imgname:~0,25%" > nul`

Comment: taskkill change its exit code only if you use /F , i just tested with a suspended process then run taskkill without /f, I got `SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process with PID 30564`. and exit code is always 0 . win7 64

Comment: @BadrElmers: The message suggests that taskkill ended with the exit code of 0 (since it was a success). If there were an issue sending the termination signal to the process, the exit code would've been different. In particular, try using taskkill without the /f on a non-existent process and check the exit code.  In my case the exit code still satisfied the `if errorlevel 128` condition (Win7 x64).

Answer (score 3):

That's why it's not working because you code something that is not right, that's why it always exit and the script executer will read it as not operable batch file that prevent it to exit and stop
so it must be

```
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq Notepad.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Notepad.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
msg * Program is running
goto Exit
)
else if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
msg * Program is not running
goto Exit
)
```

rather than

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "notepad.exe"
exit
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set run=
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" | find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 set run=yes
if "%run%"=="yes" echo notepad is running
if "%run%"=="" echo notepad is not running
pause
```