# Batch file for “if an 'exe' is not running in (task manager) then execute this task”?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I don't know anything about batch files and I am making one for something. I want to write a batch file which will **keep running in background** which itself will deal with making sure if 'java.exe' is running and if it's not then it will trigger other batch file (**say 'abc.bat'**)

This 'abc.batch' sets some parameters and **launches 'java.exe'** which executes those parameters. I want this 'java.exe' to keep running and if anyone closes it, it should restart immediately by executing 'abc.bat'. Moreover, I don't want to make changes in 'abc.bat'.

If it's confusing, I would like to apologize for my writing skills and I would like you to ask for clarification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch program to to check if process exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449034/batch-program-to-to-check-if-process-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JSCRIPT COMMENT **


@echo off

set process_to_check=java.exe
:repeat

cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" | find /i "%process_to_check%" >nul 2>&1 && (
    echo process %process_to_check%  is running
) || (
    echo process %process_to_check%  is not running
    call abc.bat
)
rem wait 5 minutes
ping localhost -n 1 -w 300000 >nul
exit /b

************** end of JSCRIPT COMMENT **/


var winmgmts = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
var colProcess = winmgmts.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process");
var processes =  new Enumerator(colProcess);
for (;!processes.atEnd();processes.moveNext()) {
    var process=processes.item();
    WScript.Echo( process.processID + "   " + process.Name );
}
```