# Detect if specific R script is running in Windows batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd

I have a .bat file that works great to detect if Rscript.exe is running, and if not it will launch a specific Rscript file. Below is the code, which was inspired by this SO Q&A [Batch program to to check if process exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449034/batch-program-to-to-check-if-process-exists#answer-38049684):

```
cd C:\R\Scripts
tasklist | find /i "Rscript.exe" && echo process "Rscript.exe" is running. || 
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" 
"C:\R\Script_1.R"
```

However, as opposed to simply checking if the Rscript.exe process itself is running, I want to detect if Rscript.exe is running the specific Script_1.R file. This way, I can have individual .bat files for each R script file. I wouldn't want to run all the scripts from one .bat file because I wouldn't want to relaunch all the scripts, just the scripts which aren't currently running.

Comment: Does `TASKLIST /V` show anything about the script being run?

Comment: @lit it shows some details like how much memory but not the script name I am looking for.