# find specific process is running or not using Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: php, process, window, scheduled-tasks, taskmanager

I want to check whether `xyz.exe` process is running in  window processes,For that I want to create a task scheduler that will check for `xyz.exe` in every 30 minutes and if it is not running then run it

Answer (score 0):

use "tasklist" cmd in a batch program, or see this full answer here -

[How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)