# Perform summation of integers on each line in a file in `cmd`

Tags: batch-file, cmd, arithmetic-expressions

Time for some command line fu in the least fu conducive shell, `cmd.exe`.

How can I perform a summation of integers contained in a file?

You might consider the following to work:

```
taskkill /f /im rsync.exe
echo %errorlevel% > %temp%/kill_site.log
taskkill /f /im ssh.exe
echo %errorlevel% >> %temp%/kill_site.log
taskkill /f /im 7za.exe
echo %errorlevel% >> %temp%/kill_site.log
set /a errorresult=1
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (%temp%/kill_site.log) do set /A errorresult=%%G+%errorresult%
```

But, it appears that `%errorresult%` will always be the value before the `for` loop during the `for` loop.  Meaning, the resulting `%errorlevel%` always has [the integer value of the last line in `%temp%/kill_site.log`] + [the `%errorlevel%` set, which is `1`].

In the case of exit codes provided by `taskkill`, if `taskkill` succeeds in killing an existing process, the exit code is `0`, then resulting `%errorresult%` in this case will be `1`.  If a process doesn't exist when `taskkill` is called to kill it, the exit code is `128`; in this case the `%errorresult% will be`129`.

I'd like `%errorresult%` to be the total of all integers contained on lines in  `%temp%/kill_site.log`.  How do I do this?

**[update]**

Thanks to Stephen's answer below, I have a final script as follows that I wanted to include for future reference by other users:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
taskkill /f /im rsync.exe
echo %errorlevel% > %temp%/kill_site.log
taskkill /f /im ssh.exe
echo %errorlevel% >> %temp%/kill_site.log
taskkill /f /im 7za.exe
echo %errorlevel% >> %temp%/kill_site.log
set /a errorresult=1
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (%temp%/kill_site.log) do set /A errorresult=%%G+!errorresult!
if %errorresult% lss 255 sendmail.vbs && eventcreate /l application /so backup_scripts /t warning /id 1 /d "website rsync has to be killed because it was long running."
endlocal
```

It utilizes [`endlocal`](http://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html).

I also just realized this is a bit backwards, as I should be checking if the processes are running previous to taking any invalid action against the non-existent processes, but the question is still resolved.  [Finding if a specific running process exists with a batch script actually uses a similar method of checking the `%errorlevel%` is also quite easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329790/843000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within a `for`loop you need [delayed expansion for your variables](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):
use

`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

at the beginning of your batchfile
and change your for-loop to

`for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (%temp%/kill_site.log) do set /A errorresult=%%G+!errorresult!`

This is because in your for-loop %errorresult% will always use the value at Parse-time. !errorresult! will use the value at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Stephan's answer works fine, but there is a simpler method that doesn't require delayed expansion.

The SET /A command does its own expansion of variable names, and it always uses the current value.

```
set /a errorresult=1
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (%temp%/kill_site.log) do set /A errorresult=%%G+errorresult
```

Or better yet

```
set /a errorresult=1
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in (%temp%/kill_site.log) do set /A errorresult+=%%G
```

*Note - I don't understand why you initialize errorresult to 1. I should think 0 would make more sense.*

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  I didn't know that `cmd` supported setting values using that style of operator!  I initialize it only for reference.  In my production script, I do not initialize it to 1, but accept 0.  I'll take a look Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non portable solution, but it is NOT the answer, but may assist others that come across this problem in the future:

```
taskkill /f /im rsync.exe
echo %errorlevel% > "%temp%/kill_site.log"
set /p res1=< "%temp%/kill_site.log"
echo > "%temp%/kill_site.log"
taskkill /f /im ssh.exe
echo %errorlevel% > "%temp%/kill_site.log"
set /p res2=< "%temp%/kill_site.log"
echo > "%temp%/kill_site.log"
taskkill /f /im 7za.exe
echo %errorlevel% > "%temp%/kill_site.log"
set /p res3=< "%temp%/kill_site.log"
echo > "%temp%/kill_site.log"
set /A errorresult=%res1% + %res2% + %res3%
```

I have marked this as a community wiki as the question is still pending an answer.