# I am writing a simple batch file to start programs

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a simple batch file to start  programs.

What command(s) do I use to have the batch file FIRST check (automatically) to see if a program is running, and run the program if it is NOT already running?

[[ Thanks in advance, I've looked and I just can't seem to find the answer. ]]

Comment: Have you seen this? Seems to do what you want...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq processName.exe" /FI "status eq running" | find /I /N "processName.exe">NUL
IF ("%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Process is running) ELSE (start "processName.exe")
```