# Check if a process is running or not?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

I want to check if a process is running or not ?
if the process is not running, then i execute it (in this example I took the calculator with process name = calc.exe)
I started the batch script, but I have a syntax problem I believe !

```
@echo off
Set MyProcess=calc.exe
echo %MyProcess%
pause
for /f "tokens=1" %%i In ('tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%"') do set ff=%%i
echo %ff%
If /i %ff%==%MyProcess% (Echo %ff% est en cours d^'execution) Else (Start %MyProcess%)
pause
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Except the `Info:` output everything works fine, doesn't it?

Comment: You will have problems with executables that have spaces or & in their name.

Comment: It's a stupid way to start calc. Is your problem with calc or another program?

Comment: So, i want to thank you all for your reply and your solutions, so in the end, i took the solution of foxidrive that worked as a charm for me and this what i expect to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to do it using your code as a base:

```
@echo off
Set "MyProcess=calc.exe"
echo "%MyProcess%"
tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%" >nul
If not errorlevel 1 (Echo "%MyProcess%" est en cours d^'execution) else (start "" "%MyProcess%")
pause
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try like this:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq calc.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "calc.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" 
echo Running
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work: find: '/I': No such file or directory | find: '/N': No such file or directory | find: 'hh.exe': No such file or directoy | The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

**My solution in Vbscript (°_^)**

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws,MyApplication,MyProcess
Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyApplication = "%Programfiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
MyProcess = "WinRAR.exe"
Do
'We check if the process is not running so we execute it
    If CheckProcess(MyProcess) = False then 
        Call Executer(DblQuote(MyApplication),0)'0 to Hide the console
'We made ​​a one-minute break and continue in our loop to check 
'whether or not our process exists(in our case = WinRAR.exe)
        Pause(1)
    End if
Loop
'***********************************************************************************************
Function CheckProcess(MyProcess)
    Dim strComputer,objWMIService,colProcessList
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select Name from Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '" & MyProcess & "%'")
        If colProcessList.count > 0 then
            CheckProcess = MyProcess & " is running"
            CheckProcess = True
        else
            CheckProcess = MyProcess & " is not running"
            CheckProcess = False
        End if
    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set colProcessList = Nothing
End Function
'***********************************************************************************************
    Sub Pause(NMins)
        Wscript.Sleep(NMins*1000*60)
    End Sub  
'***********************************************************************************************
 Function Executer(StrCmd,Console)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Resultat
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'La valeur 0 pour cacher la console MS-DOS
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
        Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,True)
        If Resultat = 0 Then
        Else
            MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
        End If
    End If
'La valeur 1 pour montrer la console MS-DOS
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
        Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,False)
        If Resultat = 0 Then
        Else
            MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
        End If
    End If
    Executer = Resultat
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I also found another way to achieve continuously check (in loop) the existence of process "WinRAR.exe" (as an example of application to check) so we can change of course the path and the process name to check.

```
@echo off
Set "MyApplication=%Programfiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
Set "MyProcess=WinRAR.exe"
Color 9B
Title Verification de l^'execution du processus "%MyProcess%" by Hackoo
mode con cols=75 lines=2
:start
cls
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %MyProcess%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%" >nul
If not errorlevel 1 (Echo "%MyProcess%" est en cours d^'execution) else (start "" "%MyApplication%")
ping -n 60 127.0.0.1 >nul 
goto start
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently when I wanted to open up an application only if the process for it didn't already exist.

```
TASKLIST | FINDSTR myProgram
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 ("your conditions here")
```

You can check to see if a program is in the tasklist. Findstr on the tasklist will return an errorlevel of 0 if it is in the tasklist. You can make use of this to build out your conditions after the check.

```
TASKLIST | FINDSTR git-bash || START "" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

^ Above is my one line solution to open up git-bash if there isn't already an instance up.