# How to tell if a process is running via batch or script file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

How can I tell if a specific process is running using a batch file?

For example, How can I tell if `notepad.exe` is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell has an in-built function. **Get-Process**
Get-Process will tell you about all the processes. If you wish to filter with a particular one then use :

> Get-Process|?{$_.Name -eq 'Notepad'}

Screenshots are for reference:

**Type Powershell in cmd prompt:**

[image]

**Run the above query. If the notepad is running. It will show you:**
[image]

Hope it helps...

Comment: type first powershell in cmd prompt. Then run the above command what I pasted.  If you directly using cmd prompt then the pipeline wont work because the values which are passed after the pipe as inputs are powershell cmdlets. Thats why it is not returning anything.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following proposal (run in your batch file):

```
tasklist | findstr /R ^notepad.exe
```

Simple, but works!

```
tasklist /?
```

Will show you a lot of great options for filtering and managing your output.

```
findstr /?
```

Will also show you a great set of options to search and filter the output of `tasklist`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer, just one problem: the execution time for this takes 10+ seconds! Is there and way to do this in a shorter time?

Comment: Do you have a lot of processes running? It's running very fast for me...

Comment: Yes I tend to have quite a few processes running at a time.

Comment: That might be the cause. I've seen cases where `tasklist` was slow. I don't have a solution for this. Sorry...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in batch file :

This one is inspired from [Check if a process is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not)

```bat
@echo off
Title Check for running process . . .
mode con cols=50 lines=3
set "MyProcess=notepad.exe"
set delay=5
:Main
cls
Tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MyProcess%" | find /I "%MyProcess%">nul && (
    echo( & Color 9A
    echo         PROCESS "%MyProcess%" IS RUNNING !
)||(
    echo( & Color 4C
    echo        PROCESS "%MyProcess%" IS NOT RUNNING !
)
Timeout /T %delay% /nobreak>nul
Goto Main
```