# How to check if a program is already running within a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, shortcut

I want to make a batch file to run a couple of programs but I also want to add a built in check for one of the two to not run if it's already open, since it I use it with other programs as well.

This is my current code without the check:

```
@echo off

cd "B:\Program Files (x86)\Borderless Gaming
start BorderlessGaming.exe"

cd "B:\Games\Madden NFL 20
start Madden20.exe"

exit
```

Comment: Check this ==> [Check if a process is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a process is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not)