# How to do the loop which can check the process by the bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im a newbie in the cmd, and if you can just help me to do the batch while for Windows. This program must check the process while script is opened. If it doesn`t launched it will be open. If you can help me, just show me a code and explain how it works, please.

Comment: And you can take a look here too ==> [Check if a process is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked before this question here [Check if a process is running or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not?answertab=active#tab-top)

And here is a little tweak to run it in loop :

```batch
    @echo off
    Title How to do the loop which can check the process by the bat file
    Color 0B
    Set "MyProcess=Notepad.exe"
    
    :CheckProcess_in_Loop
    cls
    Tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%" >nul
    If not errorlevel 1 (Echo "%MyProcess%" is running !) else (start "" "%MyProcess%")
    @REM Make a Timeout with 30 seconds
    Timeout /T 30 /NoBreak>nul
    Goto CheckProcess_in_Loop
```