# Launch if Process Not Running, Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I want to auto-launch an application (specifically Outlook.exe) if it is not already running. I wanted to do this through the Windows 7 task scheduler, which meant the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script) did not work when I tried to execute it on one line by replacing the newline with &. It would launch outlook no matter if it was running or closed.

`tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "outlook.exe">NUL & if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"`

Comment: As mentioned in this alternate version of the question, `tasklist.exe` can truncate program names.  https://superuser.com/a/1536680/311792

Answer (score 3):

Just to make a quick fix so the batch exits after successfully opening the file.

I added start ""

`cmd.exe /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" | find /I /N "outlook.exe" ||start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"`

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd), which the second answer gave greater detail on the & and | options.

This is what ended up running well for me: `cmd.exe /c tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" | find /I /N "outlook.exe" || "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"`

More details:
|| [...]  command1 || command2
Use to run the command following || **only if the command preceding || fails**. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then runs the second command only if the first command did not complete successfully (receives an error code greater than zero).