# Automatically start java app when it stops

Tags: java, windows, powershell

Anyone knows how I can automatically start a java server in batch file when it stops running?

I have the following batch file below but it only starts the server.

//test.bat

    start java -jar myserver.jar

Comment: Well with cygwin you could run a cron job to check if it's running then start it if it's not.  There might be a powershell alternative that I don't know of.

Comment: You need to figure out when the application is no longer running and then run your existing batch file. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Comment: @MarsAtomic thanks for answering. Ive already looked at that link however I don't know what to pass on the IMAGENAME part tried inserting the name of my jar but it doesn't work

Comment: When you run your Java server, what's its name in Task Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can use everyone's favorite, goto:

```
:loop
java -jar myserver.jar
goto loop
```

Comment: hi i used this previously but this will spawn a lot of instances of my myserver.jar 100 or more times in a second