# detect whether web browser is open or close using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to access my web browser using a batch file.Is there a way of knowing whether any web browser is open or not using a batch file? Take any browser for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. The command `tasklist` returns you a list of running tasks:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET running=0
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"firefox32.exe"') DO SET running=1
IF %running%==1 ECHO Firefox is running!
PAUSE
```

This checks whether Firefox is running.

Comment: I have just started using stackoverflow. An up vote requires 15 reputation it seems

Comment: The script is not working. I want to check for chrome and i typed thisFOR /f "tokens=*" %%A IN ('tasklist^ /v^| findstr /i /c:"chrome.exe"') DO SET running=1

Comment: Please post your code. If your are checking more than one browser and always using the variable `running` you have to have to add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`in the second line and access `running` as `!running!` instead of `%running%`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Doing: (you can use 'Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion' for displaying a variable as !variable! instead of %variable%. In this case, I won't do it.)

```
@echo off

echo ' > %userprofile%\Desktop\tasklist1.txt
tasklist >> %userprofile%\Desktop\tasklist1.txt

for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('findstr /i "' firefox.exe" %userprofile%\Desktop\tasklist1.txt') do (
set running=%%a
)

if %running% == ' (
echo Firefox is not running.
) else ( 
echo Firefox is running!
)
pause
```