# How to check if batch process ran

Tags: batch-file

I just created a batch job 'calculate.bat' and double clicked it. I just want to see if it's running or not. How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Comment: How do I save the scripts and how do I run them? I save them as bat files and just double click too?

Answer (score 0):

If it is running for a long time, you should be able to see it by its title under task manager.