# Ways to verify and restart if a local (or intranet) webpage on IE is open

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I have a kiosk that displays a rolling set of pictures (i.e. slideshow).  Sometimes Internet Explorer crashes.

I'm hoping to create a script that can detect if IE crashed.  Either batch, or PHP.

Preferably, I'd like to do this all within windows.  We have access to a linux environment, but our kiosks are maintained on a central windows kiosk server.

My idea was to use php in a background tab and listen on a socket, and use a remote windows box to attempt connecting on that socket (possibly on another php based tab); if the socket was not open, then a mail function would send out an email.

Ideally though, it would be nice if this could be ran locally on the kiosk vs a remote solution.  One that might interact with a php localhost page (or not), and restart when it doesn't get a response.

We could also maybe modify the host page that does the slideshow rather than a separate tab.

Anyone got any more efficient ideas on how I can implement this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script check every minute if its not runng run from command line

Comment: IE is frozen in the background (still running?), and a message shows that it has crashed but doesn't close until acknowledged.  I'm afraid this might not detect if IE has crashed or not as I believe the process is still open.  That's why I was thinking a php solution would be a better solution because it could detect if an open page is still functioning.

Comment: I would think you'd need .NET (i.e. C#/VB.NET) for this, like a Windows Service running in the background

Comment: you could just kill and restart it hourly regardless of state. but i guess an JQ scrip could poke a php script every minute to say its ok - log that. with another script check that it has logged its ok state every X minutes- if not kill it and restart