# Detect a running program and launch a different one

Tags: windows

I have a scenario in Windoze where I'd like to monitor for program A to be running before launching program B. I've google'd for related topics and all I've come across are posts for using batch files to kick off multiple apps in sequence (with/out delays). The use case I'm facing is that the user can download a file which causes program A to launch, so I don't always know when A will be started (i.e. can't just make a batch file with a shortcut on the desktop for the user).

I'd like to find a somewhat native solution that would routinely scan for program A running (could simply set up a Task that repeats) and then kicks off program B.

If a more complex method needs to be employed, so be it, but I'd prefer a minimally-invasive solution... simple language, simple development environment, etc.

Comment: Duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script