# Script to end a specific process

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Is it possible to create a script which would in turn end a specific process?

I need to end the chromedriver.exe (Even if more than one process running):
[image]

Comment: `Get-Process -Name "chromedriver" | Stop-Process` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [TaskKill](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb491009.aspx)

```
taskkill /F /IM processname.exe /T
```

Comment: how would i add an if statement to check first whether the process is running and then attempt to end the process? thanks again

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script

Comment: For using you should use powershell, that would be easy. Let me give the answer

Answer (score 1):

For conditional operation, you can use powershell;

```
if(Get-Process -Name ProcessName)
{
"Process is running. So ending the process"
Get-Process -Name ProcessName | Stop-Process -Force
}
Else
{
"Process is not running"
}
```