# bat file sequential issue, start a script after the first one finish

Tags: batch-file

I create a .bat file, Which will run four scripts, what I want to do is after the first three scripts finished, then start the last script, how should I do that?

```
start MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe /Session:"Yardi-brian"
timeout /t 120
start MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe /Session:"Yardi-lake"
timeout /t 120
start MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe /Session:"Yardi quan"

C:\Python27\python.exe C:\yardi_backup\detect.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/WAIT` switch for `START` and even `/B` to stop creating new `cmd.exe` window each time:

```
start /B /wait timeout /t 1
start /B /wait timeout /t 1
start /B /wait timeout /t 1
```

For more options run `START /?`. :)

In case you don't want to wait for each of the MSSQL programs, then there's no such thing that might help you unless you want to check whether a process with this name is still alive somewhere (which might collide with a process you haven't run) - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329790/5994041) explains how to.

A little example:

```
@echo off
start notepad
start notepad
start notepad

:check
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "notepad.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
    echo Program is not running
) else (
    goto check
)
```

Run this example watch what happens if you close all `NOTEPAD.EXE` windows.