# Using PHP (may be commandline using shell_exec() function), how can I determine if a Java application/jar file is currently running or not?

Tags: java, php, jar, exec, shell-exec

I have a PHP application which executes a Java .jar file through `shell_exec()`:

```
shell_exec("java jar myJarProgram.jar");
```

I have a need to determine if an instance this java program `myJarProgram.jar` is already running, because if it is not, then I can start it using the above PHP statement.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "jps" utility to grep your process with java

```
jps -mlvV | grep myJarProgram.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

jps is a good candidate for this, but please note that

> To use the `jps` command-line tool you need to install a JDK.

Otherwise, you can parse the output of another `shell_exec` call that uses `ps` with the arguments you want in order to get the running processes: at this point you can check if the process is present.

`$search_string = "[j]ava jar myJarProgram.jar";
$running = shell_exec("ps -A -ww | grep '$search_string'");`

or similar.

If `$running` is empty, you can launch the jar.

Another option is to perform everything with a single `shell_exec`, both with commands concatanation (simple `&&` and `||`) or creating a .sh script and `shell_exec`uting that.

EDIT:
According to the user comment, the script must work both for Windows and Linux.
You can use the php `PHP_OS` [predefined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) to check if it's Windows or Linux:

`if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') etc....`

If it's Linux, you can use the `shell_exec` as reported above.
If it's Windows, you can change the `shell_exec` string using the `tasklist` Windows command. I don't know it, but there are already dedicated questions and answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script).

Comment: What does `-ww` do?

Comment: And hey I need a solution which works for both Linux and Windows systems

Comment: @Shy This is the best description of its usage :) : -w Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default which is your window size.  If the -w option is specified more than once, ps will use as many columns as necessary without regard for your window size.