# .bat to check if a window or process is open or running and if it is do this if it is not do something else

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a little help here.

I need to create a .bat file to check if a process is running every 5 seconds. If the process is running then it simply resets and checks again in 5 seconds. If the process is not running, then it closes all other .bat files and restarts everything.

This is for a game server. So right now the whole process includes a few .bat files of which do different things. The initiate.bat starts the process by starting startserver.bat. startserver.bat then starts the game server, it's window opens and the server starts, it the starts the .bat file schedule.bat which sets a timer and is meant to restart the server once the timer has run out and then startserver.bat starts up anticrash.bat of which the code for it is below.

I have a feeling the code is not finding the server window or the process. I've double checked the process file name and have made sure that is correct. The title in the window for the server is simply the path to the .exe, but no matter what I've tried I can't get it to function correctly. It always ends up in a loop and not identifying the open or closed process and it simply defaults to "Server was not found!". If I swap the code it will simply loop "Server was found!" and proceed that way.

This is not the only example I've tried either. I've looked at literally every article I could find on how to check if a process or window was open. I've tried to add a title to the window and search for the title, I've tried other code configurations and if then statements and nothing works.

In the end I'd like the .bat to simply check if the server process is running or if the window is open, either way as I don't care how it identifies it, and if the server window is open and the server is running then simply recheck every 5 seconds. If it finds that the process or window was closed or ended, then it should close all other .bats and restart the process of initiating the server. It's mainly for when the server crashes I want it to restart if it does.

```
@echo off
goto check

:check
cls
echo Starting Anit Crash... Check every 5 Seconds...
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=program.exe
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% goto FOUND
echo Server was not found!
echo Server may have crashed...
timeout /t 5
echo Shutting Down Other Processes First...
taskkill /f /im "schedule.bat"
echo Server Restarting...
start cmd /k call initiate.bat
echo Exiting Anti Crash...
timeout /t 3
goto FIN
:FOUND
echo Server Was Found...
echo Server Is Active... Rechecking In 5 Seconds...
timeout /t 5
goto check
:FIN
exit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

Comment: Take a look at the Windows Task Scheduler for recurring tasks…

Answer (score 1):

It may solve your Problem

```
@echo off

:values
set EXE=safeincloud.exe

:check
cls
echo Starting Anti Crash... Check every 5 Seconds...
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq %EXE%" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "%EXE%">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto FOUND
echo Server was not found!
echo Server may be crashed...
timeout /t 5 >nul
echo Shutting Down Other Processes First...
taskkill /f /im "schedule.bat"
echo Server Restarting...
start "" "initiate.bat"
echo Exiting Anti Crash...
timeout /t 3 >nul
goto End

:FOUND
echo.
echo Server Was Found...
echo Server Is Active... Rechecking In 5 Seconds...
timeout /t 5 >nul
goto check

:End
exit
```

Source : [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)