# Batch: Action in a for loop depending on running processes

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

What's the best way to periodically check using a Windows batch script whether one or more processes are running, and then execute one block of code if any of those processes are running and a different block of code if none of them are?

I've tried using a `for` loop and setting a variable within the loop as a flag, and then executing code depending on the value of that flag using an `if` statement, but it isn't working.

The whole script is longer but I've simplified it down to a test file, checking just for either the the basic notepad or calculator apps to be running, to isolate the problem. Here's my test code (which doesn't work):

```
echo off
for /L %%A in (3,-1,1) do (

  set flag=no

  tasklist /fi "ImageName eq notepad.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "notepad.exe">NUL
  if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (set flag=yes)
  tasklist /fi "ImageName eq CalculatorApp.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "CalculatorApp.exe">NUL
  if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (set flag=yes)

  if "%flag%" == "no" ( echo Flag is no ) else (echo Flag is yes)

  timeout 60 /nobreak > NUL

)
echo on
```

Right now it outputs "Flag is no" irrespective of whether the processes are running.

What am I getting wrong? I've tried adding `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top and it made no difference. I've also tried rewriting it to use `goto`, which didn't work inside the loop, and then rewriting it again to use subroutines with `call`, but that messed up the logic because I need to not perform some action if the processes are found.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: just enabling delayed expansion is not enough. You also have to [actually use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).

Comment: shorter and not depending on delayed expansion: `tasklist |findstr /i "notepad.exe calculatorapp.exe" >nul && echo at least one of them is running || echo none of them is running`

Comment: @Stephan Thank you for the suggestions. The `tasklist` search was from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329790/3251370) - I think they'd included the extra parameters in `tasklist` so the executable names don't get truncated.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks for the pointer on how the variables should be referenced with delayed expansion as well. There are a lot of answers on this site that just suggest adding the command to enable it without mentioning anything about the variable references needing to be different, so I hadn't realised I needed to change that as well. The `for` loop version works now with delayed expansion based on the issue you pointed out, and in the meantime I'd put together a version replacing the `for` loop with `goto`. I've posted both code snippets as an answer, below, crediting your comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77551266/batch-action-in-a-for-loop-depending-on-running-processes#comment136718142_77551266) @Stephan identified that the variables were being reference incorrectly in the loop for use with `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, which explains why it didn't work when I tried it.

The following version uses `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` with the variables referenced correctly, and appears to work:

```
echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /L %%A in (3,-1,1) do (

  set flag=no

  tasklist /fi "ImageName eq notepad.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "notepad.exe">NUL
  if "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (set flag=yes)
  tasklist /fi "ImageName eq CalculatorApp.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "CalculatorApp.exe">NUL
  if "!ERRORLEVEL!"=="0" (set flag=yes)

  if "!flag!" == "no" ( echo Flag is no ) else (echo Flag is yes)

  timeout 60 /nobreak > NUL

)
echo on
```

Note that the `ERRORLEVEL` variable must be referenced using exclamation marks, as well as the `flag` variable.

For those who don't wish to use `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` or have reasons why it won't work for them, here is the same functionality with the `for` loop replaced with a `goto` structure instead:

```
echo off

set /a i = 3
:loop

set flag=no

tasklist /fi "ImageName eq notepad.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "notepad.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (set flag=yes)
tasklist /fi "ImageName eq CalculatorApp.exe" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "CalculatorApp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (set flag=yes)

if "%flag%" == "no" ( echo Flag is no ) else (echo Flag is yes)

timeout 60 /nobreak > NUL

set /a i = %i% - 1

if %i% GEQ 1 (goto loop)

echo on
```

Hope this is helpful for anyone struggling with a similar issue.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the query - the requirement is for the solution to identify whether any of the processes are running. I've edited the first paragraph in the question body to avoid any confusion.